# Does "will you stop here, please" express a command or exhortation?

Tags: meaning

> Will you stop here, please.

Does the sentence express a command or exhortation?

Is it equivalent to say, "Stop here!" or does it have an additional/different meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will you stop here, please.

is a command - but is more polite than simply using the imperative "stop here".

The use of "will" is what makes it sound more like a command than a request, compared to:

> *Polite but firm:* Would you stop here, please.
>
> *Polite:* Could you stop here, please.
>
> *More polite:* Would you mind stopping here, please.

Answer (score 1):

These are not equivalent sentences because of the "here." "Stop here, please," would be a request of a taxi driver, possibly, while "Stop it!" means stop whatever you're doing right now, with no reference to location. As Steve notes, there's a whole spectrum of politeness to these requests.  Rule of thumb: the more syllables in the statement, the more polite.

Comment: I corrected the second example: it was not supposed to be _Stop it!_